# How do you get an indeterminate progress bar to run on a worker thread on Android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have the following code:

```
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/learning_directions_label"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
```

But i'm not sure whether outputting this runs on the UI thread or on a worker thread w/o any logic added?  How could I put this on a worker thread?

Comment: you can't. Use the UI Thread to show  and dismiss it, using the delegate pattern from the worker thread to communicate with the UI thread

Comment: You definitely can't put it on a regular worker `Thread`. Anything having to do with the UI has to run on the UI `Thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ProgressBar` itself animates on the UI thread without further intervention.

If you want to tie the `ProgressBar` to some work you want to do, do the following using an `AsyncTask`

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> () {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(Void aVoid) {
        // make your ProgressBar visible here, this runs on UI Thread
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // do your work here, this runs on BG thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        // hide your Progress bar here, this runs on UI thread
    }
}.execute();
```